# Learning Python with Chromebook. Having trouble importing external modules into IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I have had some issues with importing external modules into IDLE on chromebook. 
For example I would like to start with termcolor. I was able to download termcolor through the linux shell using the command:

```
python3 -m pip install termcolor
```

It downloads into a folder:

```
./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

I would now like to use termcolor in IDLE.

I have not been able to successfully change the directory that termcolor gets downloaded into therefore it was difficult to access within IDLE. However, I was able to use the following command to access that directory:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(('./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages'))
```

I was then able to import termcolor and use it a little. However, when I try to do something like:

```
print(termcolor.colored('hi'))
```

I get the result:

```
hi[0m
```

I would like to try and get everything sorted out since as I progress towards more advanced modules, I would like to not run into similar problems. I have though about getting a different laptop such as a mac to maybe simplify things since Chromebook may make things more difficult for beginners.

So my questions would be:
1) Can I add into IDLE pathbrowswer `./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages?`

2) How do I correct so I do not get `hi[0m` as a result?

Comment: It's often a bad idea to do any coding on a chromebook, this is a good example

Comment: `termcolor` cannot work within IDLE - it requires a terminal that actually implements control codes for changing colors.  IDLE's shell window only supports plain text.

Comment: You should not have to fiddle with sys.path.  There are maybe 50 questions and answers about using pip properly to install 3rd party packages for the python you want to run the package.  jasonharper is correct about the current state of IDLE Shell.